# Debian device is not able to access internet

Tags: debian, linux-networking

I am trying to access internet on a embedded debain device but the device is not able to ping the IP addresses outside the `LAN` network but device is able to ping the IP addresses of the `LAN` network.

I was trying to add default gateway by `route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0` but it says `SIOCADDRT: No such process`.
Also tried `/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 eth0` but it also says `SIOCADDRT: No such process`.

**The default gateway of LAN network is 192.168.1.1.**

Can anyone help me to make this device able to ping the internet addresses?

Here are some commands outputs

```
uname -a --> Linux debian 2.6.34.9 #1 PREEMPT Thu Sep 1 18:19:33 PHT 2011 armv5tel GNU/Linux
```

**`ifconfig`**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:db:00:1a:18
          inet addr:192.168.1.70  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:dbff:fe00:1a18/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:445358 (434.9 KiB)  TX bytes:124910 (121.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:11

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:638 (638.0 B)  TX bytes:638 (638.0 B)
```

**`route -n`**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**`cat /etc/resolv.conf`**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

**`cat /etc/network/interfaces`**

```
# Used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8). See the interfaces(5) manpage or
# /usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples for more information.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

This should be enough. If you want specify interface also, then try

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but This command's output is SIOCADDRT: No such process.

Comment: Try to create a host route to default-gateway via your eth0
`route add -host 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`, the try to add default route again

Comment: Same output again after adding host

Comment: Is host 192.168.1.1 reachable from your debian device?

Comment: yes its pinging

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dhcp server is broken.

According to your question, the dhcp server does not provides the correct gateway to your client.

Try setting a static IP adress by ediiting /etc/network/interfaces

(you'll find correct syntax on the internet).